# Add time stamp to date in SQLserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

Below fetches the last monday from the current date.

```
 SELECT cast (DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0) as datetime)
```

but it displays date as timestamp all zeros like this

```
2014-05-26 00:00:00.000
```

I want the time stamp to be at 6 am like this

```
05-26-2014 06:00:00
```

or else its ok even if I get the the exact last monday date with the current GETDATE() timestamp.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do one more `DATEADD` and add 6 more hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding 6 hours

```
 SELECT cast (DATEADD(HH,6,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it using one of the many [built-in formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).

This will display it in the format:

- MM-DD-YYYY 06:00:00

and still fetch the last Monday date you want.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0), 110) + ' 06:00:00'
```